# Alesis DM Lite to Presonus 1818vsl

Tags: drums, drum-kits

Is Alesis DM lite compatible to Presonus 1818vsl cuz I'm gonna use an app called Auria on iPad

Comment: Can you give more information about that you're trying to use Auria for and how Alesis and Presonus relate to your use of Auria?

Answer (score 1):

I think it seems that you want to record the Alesis DM Lite through the Presonus audio interface then the interface to Auria